# Naive bayes classifiers are bad estimators

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes

I read this in the Scikit-learn guide (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html):

> [...] although naive Bayes is known as a decent classifier,
> it is known to be a bad estimator, so the probability outputs
> from predict_proba are not to be taken too seriously'

Bad and decent at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's put some context, with a quote from the [2nd edition of Francois Chollet's book on Deep Learning](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python-second-edition), that I believe will shed light on your interrogation. The point is that Naive Bayes is one of the 1st so-called Machine learning classifier, which assumes that the features in the input data are all independent (Naive assumption), still providing a "descent" result; but, as compared to more recent neural networks, the performance on classification tasks is often much lower.

> Naive Bayes is a type of machine-learning classifier based on applying Bayes' theorem while assuming that the features in the input data are all independent (a strong, or “naive” assumption, which is where the name comes from). This form of data analysis predates computers and was applied by hand decades before its first computer implementation (most likely dating back to the 1950s). Bayes' theorem and the foundations of statistics date back to the eighteenth century, and these are all you need to start using Naive Bayes classifiers.

> A closely related model is the logistic regression (logreg for short),
> which is sometimes considered to be the “hello world” of modern
> machine learning. Don’t be misled by its name—logreg is a
> classification algorithm rather than a regression algorithm. Much like
> Naive Bayes, logreg predates computing by a long time, yet it’s still
> useful to this day, thanks to its simple and versatile nature. It’s
> often the first thing a data scientist will try on a dataset to get a
> feel for the classification task at hand.